# Using numbers from CSS class as CSS values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to streamline CSS styling. Is it possible to use a number in the CSS class as a value to be applied? Like parameters in a PHP or JavaScript function

Ex.

```
<div class="pad-left-35">Div with 35px padding left </div>
<div class="pad-left-10">Div with 10px padding left </div>

.pad-left-[value] { padding-left: 'value'px; }
.color-[value] { color: 'value'; }
```

Comment: No with pure CSS AFAIK

Comment: Saludos mxcoder .. veo que eres de Mexico.. gracias .. me imaginaba que no era posible

Comment: Use SCSS for creating such classes

Comment: De nada / You're welcome! Hope you find a good solution, maybe CSS variables?

Comment: Thanks  Yashwardhan .. Ill look up SCSS.. never used it..

Comment: @ADQuin it is very easy.. GO ahead and learn.

Comment: Variables I don't think will work.. i need it to be on demand.. BTW this is my first time asking here..  Why is my post displaying -2 votes?

Comment: If you want to embed your styling in the HTML markup, use the `style` attribute. No need to re-invent inline styles through the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, it's impossible, and it will probably always be. However, when the new CSS drafts will be approved, you will be able do to a similar thing with custom attributes. For example, if you have `<div padding="35">...</div>` you will be able to set its padding like this:

```
div /* or whatever selector you would like to use */ {
    padding: attr(padding px);
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). Unfortunately, this draft has not been approved yet. So, until then, you will either set some standard paddings - like `padding-4`, `padding-8`, `padding-12`, ... - or use a SASS/SCSS `foreach` loop, like this:

```
@for $padding from 1 to 13 {
    .padding-#{$padding} {
        padding: $padding + px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, however, using :root, you can add parameters as shown in the code below, hope this helps.

```
:root {
    --main-bg-color: coral;
    --padding: 5px;
}  

#div1 {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
    padding: var(--padding);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Obada.. I'm familiar with CSS custom properties. I'ts not what I was looking for..   I needed the value to be used to be set in the class name itself..  Thanks anyway .. I'm checking out SCSS as recommended by another user

Comment: Anytime Quin, I was gonna recommend 'sass', just wanted to rule this out first.

Comment: As for the -2 on your question, it's because people voted that you didnt ask the question properly. To avoid such negative votes, try posting what you've tried to do as well. Enjoy Stack!

Comment: That's great, I don't believe it should've been voted down, however people are picky and want to see research effort in the question.

Comment: I thought that a straight forward approach when asking was better..  less confusing and to the point..  whatever...   Thanks anyway Obada.. have a good weekend..